clickable map not responding
Hi I am trying to make my first clickable map in a hmtl page, but for some reason the link does not work.
The image size is correct (500px 250px)
The coordinates are correct in relation to the image (verified in paint)
The URL works
What could possibly be wrong? (the area shape default works)
Here is the code:
<!DOCTYPE_html>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>いろんなところにジャンプ</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>いろんなところにジャンプ</h1>
        <img src="ClickMap.gif" alt="clickmap" usemap="#map1" style="width:500px; height:250px">
        <map name="map1">
            <area shape="rect" coord="105,72,395,195" alt="piku1" href="https://www.nintendo.com/jp/character/pikmin/index.html">
            <area shape="default" alt="Other" href="https://www.nintendo.com/jp/character/pikmin/schedule/index.html?date=20240504">
        </map>
    </body>
</html>

Appreciate any  help!!!!
Thank you
It says in the initial message

I think you have a small typo in your  tag change, coord with coords
    <area shape="rect" coords="105,72,395,195" alt="piku1" href="https://www.nintendo.com/jp/character/pikmin/index.html">

Let me know if it works
